# No module named 'selenium.common'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, spyder

I am trying to run this code on a Windows 64-bit system.

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium import webdriver
```

The error I get is: No module named 'selenium.common'

I have already installed selenium in the same directory as Python using

```py
pip install selenium
```

After installing:

```py
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38>pip install selenium
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.9)
```

I checked the versions as well

```py
C:\Users\user>pip -V
pip 21.1.1 from c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

C:\Users\user>python -V
Python 3.8.2
```

I tried running this using Spyder as well as Atom but I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

try this command -

```
pip3 install selenium
```

or

```
python -m pip install -U selenium
```

Comment: I'm using Windows, not Linux. When I try to run this, I get:
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I have edited my answer. please refresh your page.

Comment: Tried both, getting: Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\users\hansi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\hansi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.9) .
And the same error

Comment: Try manually installing selenium as described in [this](https://shashanksrivastava.medium.com/how-to-fix-no-module-named-selenium-error-in-python-3-da3fd7b61485) link.